# How to make permanent settings to chrome driver

Tags: robotframework, selenium-chromedriver

As chrome has blocked Java, Silverlight and other plugins by default now. So to make it work we need to Enable the NPAPI in chrome://flags and restart the browser to make the setting into effect,the same needs to be done in chrome driver however the setting gets lost after restarting the chrome driver, is there any way to make the permanent settings into chrome driver?

Comment: I think correct way to modify Chrome settings in Selenium is to use desired_capabilities setting when starting browser.

Comment: I am using Robot framework and want my chromdriver to copy settings which are already made in chrome, Please advice

Answer (score 3):

My earlier comment was wrong because desired capabilities is for non-browser specific settings like proxy address. If you want to modify Chrome behavior, you need to use ChromeOptions. Create Webdriver keyword was created for special cases like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow
    ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      always-authorize-plugins
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      enable-npapi
    Create WebDriver  Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    https://www.java.com/verify
    Close All Browsers
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new instance[profile] of the chrome browser every time,  npapi flag can be enabled by using following line:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome,:switches => %w[--enable-npapi]
```