# Start a chrome instance with CORS using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am a newbie to Robot Framework but wanted to ask if it was possible to initiate a Chrome instance with CORS enabled?

```
Run process  open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args  --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome_dev_session  --disable-web-security  --allow-running-insecure-content  --new-window
```

I have tried the above but unfortunately get an error when running

`Keyword 'Process.Run Process' got positional argument after named arguments.`

I have also tried without the double spacing between the arguments

```
Run process open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome_dev_session --disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content --new-window
```

However got the following error

```
Keyword 'Process.Run Process' expected at least 1 non-keyword argument, got 0.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have a test to verify your use case I'm just going to share some results of a short investigation.

The way you start Chrome to run your test is not correct. On StackOverflow a similar question with regards to Chrome holds a [fine example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29966576/6152737) of how to start Chrome with a specific settings set. For example a proxy.

Using that mechanism it should be possible to set your specific arguments like so:

```
    *** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Stackoverflow
    ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      disable-web-security
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      allow-running-insecure-content
    Call Method    ${options}    add_argument      user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome_dev_session
    Create WebDriver  Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    https://www.java.com/verify
    Close All Browsers
```

This should allow you to start Chrome with the specific settings you need to perform your local tests.